# Use hardcoded json strings when parsing with gson

Tags: json, gson, hardcoded

sorry if the question have been answered previously but I didn't find anything.

The problem is as follows: I use GSON to serialize/deserialize my json requests and responses into objects. It works well, but lately I've bumped into a problem when serializing:

I want to send a complex request. Since I didn't designed the server side I have to accommodate my self with what they give me, so I have this json:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "n",
  "description": "some description",
  "type": 1,
  "channel": 0,
  "styles": [{
    "styleID": 1,
    "style": {... // lots of properties nested one inside another }
  }]
}
```

The problem is: I cannot create a class for each subProperty of "style", which are : "events", "buttons", "labels" etc...
So I thought I'd put it like this:

```
public class MyData {
  private Integer id;
  // ...
  private String styles = getStylesJsonString(); // hardcoded styles in json format
}
```

But I can't, because in the end it becomes:

```
 "styles": "[{...}]"
```

which is invalid (according to the server).

So any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to **serialize** some classes building a JSON response like that? or do you want to **deserialize** thar JSON response into some classes?

Comment: The thing is that I need to serialize and deserialize the MyData objects into/from json, and the only relevant info is the id, the name and the type. But on the server side they are expecting much more information, such as the styles, and they need to have specific fields too. I thought I would use a hard-coded string for that.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected response as you are assigning a JSON String to a variable which is nothing more than a String itself. My suggestion use

```
private Object styles;
```

and use GSON to deserialize which would convert the result to a Map or a List of Map.